# marquee shortcode for wordpress not working

Tags: marquee

I want to add marquee tag short code its not working.How to add it in the front end ?

```
function marquee_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) 
{
    return '<marqee>'.$content.'</marqee>';
}
    add_shortcode( 'marquee', 'marquee_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_shortcode( 'marquee', function ($content = null ) {
    return (isset($content) && !empty($content))? ''.$content.'' : 'Please provide content';
});

will do the trick
```